# How to get a drop down menu in asp.net master page?

Tags: asp.net, menu, drop-down-menu

In my master page I have a table and inside that table I have these, This is for displaying the username after user login to the website. I want to have a icon when clicked it should display signout, changepassword. How can I do that. Something similar like facebook where there is a inverted triangle whenclicked displays privacy setting.

```
<td class="style1">
    <asp:Label ID="Label_Welcome"  runat="server" Text="Welcome:"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
     <asp:Label ID="Label_UsereName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this type menu can be made using jquery

refer to this link [Facebook Style CSS JQuery drop down menus](http://sammaye.wordpress.com/2010/01/23/facebook-style-css-jquery-drop-down-menus/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to look into some javascript code which will show/hide your options.

[jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [jQuery Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) would be a good place to start.